# Connecting and Using SQL Compact Edition in a WPF application

Tags: c#, wpf, database, visual-studio-2012, sql-server-ce

I am just keeping up with WPF and C#. I have written a complete desktop application and it was Ok. I am now working on a database driven application (The database is a temporary storage, the application will sync with a live server). I have chosen MsSql Compact Edition as my application database but I seem not to find any tutorial that breaks down connecting, accessing and administering the database in a WPF program. I have a good background knowledge of database, RDBMS and ORM from the likes of PHP and MySql. Moving to Desktop/MS applications, I have the following questions.

1. Creating the database (I can try this with VS 2012 but hints are welcome)
2. Adding (bundling) it to the application.
3. Performing a CRUD on it (A simple class or example)
4. Possibility of using one database in two projects of the same solution
5. Other things I should know, not leaving out available ORM (if they are available) and their respective documentations.

I will be glad if answers are related using a Database engine like MySql with PHP. I just need a breakdown.

Replies will be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

SqlCompact just creates a file (.sdf) on your local file system.  You can create it on the fly and then delete it when your done.. or keep it around.  Here's some code snippits I grabbed from a project I once did.  It should help with the creation/CRUD questions.

```
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;

private SqlCeConnection InitializeDatabase()
{
    string connectionString = CreateDatabase();
    SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(connectionString);
    conn.Open();

    CreateTable(conn);

    return conn;
}

private string CreateDatabase()
{
    string dbPath = String.Format("{0}scanner.sdf", _rootPath);
    if (File.Exists(dbPath))
        File.Delete(dbPath);

    string connectionString = String.Format("DataSource=\"{0}\";Max Database Size=3000;", dbPath);
    SqlCeEngine en = new SqlCeEngine(connectionString);
    en.CreateDatabase();
    en.Dispose();

    return connectionString;
}

private void CreateTable(SqlCeConnection conn)
{
    using (SqlCeCommand comm = new SqlCeCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        comm.CommandText = "CREATE TABLE gnis ([Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, [Name] [nvarchar](110) NOT NULL, [Geometry] [varbinary](429) NOT NULL)";
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

private void CreateTableIndex(SqlCeConnection conn)
{
    using (SqlCeCommand comm = new SqlCeCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        comm.CommandText = "CREATE INDEX IXgnis ON gnis ([Name]);";
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}

private void WriteFeature(SqlCeConnection conn, string name, MultiPoint multiPoint)
{
    byte[] wkb = WkbWriter.WriteWkb(multiPoint);
    using (SqlCeCommand comm = new SqlCeCommand())
    {
        comm.Connection = conn;
        comm.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        comm.CommandText = "INSERT INTO gnis ([Name], [Geometry])  VALUES (@a, @b)";
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", name);
        comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", wkb);
        comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: Big thumbs up, Hers a good head start, I got another tutorial though, with this and that one, I am ready to go.

Comment: There are some variables that are not declared and there uses are not clear, I will appreciate if you post the list of the dependencies used. Also, please what is the use of the `WkbWriter.WriteWkb(multiPoint);` method and the `MultiPoint` namespace is unknown. Thanks

Comment: It's just code snippets.. not a full class.  Just ignore the geometry stuff.